# MySQL Inner Join con columnas Id nulas

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla donde cotiene varias id relacionadas y usando inner join obtengo los datos el problema es que algunos registros no guardan una id y pongo valor Null 
y cuando ago el select con inner join no me muestra los datos con valor null

Este es el select que uso :

```
SELECT c.idCaja,c.FechaIngreso,td.nDoc,c.numDoc,d.nDescripcion,cen.nCentroCosto,c.egreso,c.tot_egresos,tp.nTipPago,c.mov_efectivo,c.saldo_efectivo,c.mov_banco,c.saldo_banco FROM caja_chica c join tipodoc td on c.idDoc=td.idDoc join descripcion d on c.idDescripcion=d.idDescripcion join centro_costo cen on  c.idCentroCoto=cen.idCentroCosto join tipopago tp on c.idTipPago=tp.idTipPago
```

Aqui una captura de la tabla y el registro :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Alguien me puede ayudar a resolver este problema?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar los inner join por left join.

```
SELECT c.idCaja,c.FechaIngreso,td.nDoc,c.numDoc,d.nDescripcion,cen.nCentroCosto,c.egreso,c.tot_egresos,tp.nTipPago,c.mov_efectivo,c.saldo_efectivo,c.mov_banco,c.saldo_banco 
FROM caja_chica c 
left join tipodoc td on c.idDoc=td.idDoc 
join descripcion d on c.idDescripcion=d.idDescripcion 
join centro_costo cen on  c.idCentroCoto=cen.idCentroCosto 
join tipopago tp on c.idTipPago=tp.idTipPago
```